# Can I Populate A Lookup/Optionset based on the results of a Lookup

Tags: c#, javascript, plugins, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm creating a Issue entity in CRM 2013.
I'm using a lookup to associate an Account to the issue.
From here I want to be able to retrieve the orders that are associated with that account to associate the issue too.

The end result would be a lookup/option set populated with the orders for the account which the user can then pick one from.

Comment: Lookup and OptionSet are two fundamentally different things. If you want to filter the Lookup on Orders you should be able to specify this in the properties of the Lookup on your Issue entity.

Comment: Hi, I understand they are different things, I included both in case one was not an option, I have selected orders on the look up but unsure how to only display the orders that is associated with the chosen account

Comment: Basically you'll have to create a view at runtime and assign it to the Order Lookup filtering for the selected Account. I'll see if I can find an example for you ...

Comment: Hi @Filburt, did you manage to find an example as this is something completely new to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a custom filter to your Lookup control at runtime (JavaScript Form customizing):

```
var accountid; // contains id from your Account Lookup control

var fetchfilter = '<filter type="and"><condition attribute="customerid" operator="eq" value="' + accountid + '" /></filter>';

Xrm.Page.getControl('YOUR_ORDER_LOOKUP_ATTRIBUTE_NAME_HERE').addCustomFilter(fetchfilter)
```

Of course you'll need to handle change events to your Account Lookup and update the filter from both the Form.Onload event and the Account Lookup OnChange event.

See MSDN [Xrm.Page.ui control (client-side reference) - Lookup control methods and events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_lookupControlMethods) for more details.

If you are new to MS CRM clientside customizing, start at [Write client side application extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309637.aspx).